# Совершенствование безопасности типов за счет явной реализации интерфейсных методов (Джефри Рихтер)

Tags: c#, интерфейс

```
public interface IComparable
{
    int CompareTo(object other);
}

internal struct SomeValueType : IComparable
{
    private int m_x;
    public SomeValueType(int x)
    {
        this.m_x = x;
    }
    
    public int CompareTo(SomeValueType other)
    {
        return (m_x - other.m_x);
    }

    int IComparable.CompareTo(object other)
    {
        return (m_x - ((SomeValueType)other).m_x);
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть данный код. В книге говорится, что при сокрытии реализации интерфейсного метода и добавлении его публичной копии с нужным типом мы получаем безопасность типа при его сравнении, убирая упаковку и проверку на этапе компиляции. Но в чем смысл тогда реализации самого интерфейса IComparable если мы не используем метод интерфейса и не можем выставить по нему ограничение. Мы получается так же можем создать экземпляр структуры без наследования от интерфейса и вызывать метод CompareTo, который стал его публичным методом. А вот в случае создания какого-то метода типа

```
public void Compare<T>(T o1, SomeValueStruct o2) where T : IComparable 
{
   o1.CompareTo(o2);
}
```

Мы все равно вызываем проверку через Object. И я не могу объяснить себе этой безопасности типов через интерфейс.

Answer (score 1):

В этом вопросе можно отметить два преимущества, 1- наличие нужного(перегруженного) компаратора точно сравнит как надо два обьекта этих типов. 2е - в случае отсутствия перегруженного метода, всегда есть общий метод реализуемый интерфейсом. Тогда всю коллекцию разнообразных обьектов мы можем представить как
List<IComparable>
и обработать на сравнение, поиск искомого. А это основная причина наличия интерфейсов.

Comment: Так в этом и есть основная идея данной главы, что мы стараемся исключить проверку через Object т.к. он может принять любой тип и выдать ошибку в рантайме. Получается не точная безопасность типов, а надежда, что кто-то не приведет к типу IComparable и не попытается проверить с иным типом. Но в таком случае лучше сразу опустить реализацию интерфейса. Про обобщенные интерфейсы пока ничего не говорю, они помогут решить эту проблему.